# PHP Notice: Undefined index: url

Tags: php

Any reason why i'm getting this error

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url on line 40
```

From my code the code is used to grab link for movies from a site but as i try to grab the link i get that error so could someone point me in the right direction on solving the issue.

```
public function getMovieEmbeds($title) {
    $misc = new Misc(); 
    //Step1 find key
    $movie_url = null;
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.primewire.ag/');
    $elements = $html->find('input[name=key]',0);
    $key = null;
    if(!is_null($elements)){
        $key = $elements->value;
    }
    if(is_null($key)){
        return array();
    }

    //Step2 do search...
    $search = urlencode($title);                
    $html = file_get_html("http://www.primewire.ag/index.php?search_keywords=$search&key=$key&search_section=1");
    $elements = $html->find(".index_item h2");
    if(!is_null($elements)){
        foreach($elements as $element){
            $element_title = strtolower(strip_tags(trim(preg_replace('/\s*\([^)]*\)/', '', $element->innertext))));                 
            if ($element_title == strtolower(trim($title))) {
                $parent = $element->parent();
                $movie_url = "http://primewire.ag".$parent->href;
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
    if (is_null($movie_url)) { 
        return array();
    }

    //Step3 get embeds
    $html = file_get_html($movie_url);
    $elements = $html->find(".movie_version_link a");
    if(!is_null($elements)){
        foreach($elements as $element){
            $encoded_url = "http://primewire.ag".$element->href;
            $query = parse_url($encoded_url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
            parse_str($query,$op);
            error came from ---> $link = base64_decode($op["url"]); <--- here

            if(strpos($link, "affbuzzads")===false && strpos($link, "webtrackerplus")===false){
                $embed = $misc->buildEmbed($link);
                if ($embed) {
                    $embeds[] = array(
                        "embed" => $embed,
                        "link" => $link,
                        "language" => "ENG",
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $embeds;
    }
    return array(); 
}
```

could some one please help me it would be most helpful

Comment: du have done a var_dump($op) and looked if there is an index namend url?

Comment: if you are not aware those sites have been blocked in UK

Answer (score 2):

parse_str returns an array of the parameters on a URL, as if it was in the $_GET array.

It would only contain a 'url' value if the url you used had a parameter 'url'

E.g. it was along the lines of:

```
http://example.com/?url=urlvalue
```

Therefore, if $element->href (and therefore $encoded_url and $query) does not contain a parameter named 'url' in it you'll not get an index in the $op array of 'url'

See the documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php